# Can't get Automapper to return the derived type when the input is IQueryable

Tags: c#, polymorphism, automapper, iqueryable

I can get Automapper's `.Map` to return the derived type, but not in an `IQueryable`.

Data structure:

```
public class Order { }
public class OnlineOrder : Order { }
public class MailOrder : Order { }

public class OrderDto { }
public class OnlineOrderDto : OrderDto { }
public class MailOrderDto : OrderDto { }
```

Setup (~copied [from documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance)):

```
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
        .Include<OnlineOrder, OnlineOrderDto>()
        .Include<MailOrder, MailOrderDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<OnlineOrder, OnlineOrderDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<MailOrder, MailOrderDto>();
});

var order = new OnlineOrder();
var orders = new List<Order> { order }.AsQueryable();

var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper().Map<OrderDto>(order); // is of type OnlineOrderDto, it works!
```

What I've tried:

```
var projectTo = orders.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(mapperConfiguration); // is of type OrderDto, boo!
var useAsDataSource = orders.UseAsDataSource(mapperConfiguration).For<OrderDto>(); // is of type OrderDto, boo!
```

I've looked at [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource)#useasdatasource), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965593/is-it-possible-to-map-iqueryablecatdto-to-iqueryablecatef), the [queryable extensions](http://Queryable%20Extensions), and some answers involving [LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212126/does-automapper-support-linq). I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.  See this closed bug report:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/701